# HTML5 Audio jQuery .click To Play Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need another set of eyes on this.

I have various "hover sounds" that work fine using HTML5. Now I'm trying to add "click to play" image, using jQuery to play the HTML Audio. Here is my code:

```
    $(".audio_photography").click(function(){
            photography_audio.play();
        },
        function(){
            photography_audio.pause();
        });
```

and HTML

```
        <span class="audio_photography">
            <audio id="photography_audio">
                <source src="audio/cherish-the-day.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
                <source src="audio/cherish-the-day.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></source>
            </audio>
        </span>
```

Nothing happens when clicked. I double checked the path to my mp3/ogg, and it's correct.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Just in case, here is the whole jQuery script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".main-navigation li").hover(function(){
            main_navigation_audio.play();
        },
        function(){
            main_navigation_audio.load();
        });
        $("#primary a, #secondary a, footer a").hover(function(){
            link_audio.play();
        },
        function(){
            link_audio.load();
        });
        $(".site-title a").hover(function(){
            header_audio.play();
        },
        function(){
            header_audio.load();
        });
        $("input, textarea, .site-header").hover(function(){
            input_textarea_audio.play();
        },
        function(){
            input_textarea_audio.load();
        });
        $(".audio_photography").click(function(){
            photography_audio.play();
        },
        function(){
            photography_audio.pause();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: lol. Lots of variable, but none are defined

Comment: `main_navigation_audio` where is it initialize ? Do I see the keyword `var` anywhere?

Comment: i didn't post all of the code, I tried to leave out what works, and only focus on what didn't work.

Comment: All I see is variable isn't defined anywhere. Lack information, can't help. Also function syntax error. What's with click event has 2 functions

Comment: Based on your recent comment, I realized click event can't have two functions? I removed the second function and it now works when clicked. However, I can't figure out how to make it pause if clicked again.

Comment: Yes. You didn't read the jQuery documentation correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the script I use now and it seems to work.

```
        $('.audio_photography').click(function(){
              if(photography_audio.paused){
                photography_audio.play();
               } else {
                 photography_audio.pause();
               }
        });
```